# How to install Cosmographia?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Cosmographia. On the [JPL website](https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/naif/cosmographia_components.html), there is an installer file, but once I downloaded it, I don't know what to do with it.

How can I install Cosmographia?

Comment: Please provide OS & release details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the terminal

```
chmod u+x cosmo-installer-4.0-linux
./cosmo-installer-4.0-linux
```

Or in Nautilus

- Right click and select Properties
- In Permissions tick "Allow executing file as program"
- Close dialog and double click the file

Answer (score 3):

Probably installation is possible by

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://naif.jpl.nasa.gov/pub/naif/cosmographia/packages/cosmo-installer-4.0-linux
chmod +x cosmo-installer-4.0-linux

./cosmo-installer-4.0-linux
# or with sudo
sudo ./cosmo-installer-4.0-linux
```